# SQL Statement for displaying results when searching

Tags: sql, search

Good day,

I'm having a problem when searching, say I want to find a certain university like for example,
university of nowhere, if I search for **university** or **nowhere** then I get several suggestions including **university of nowhere** which is good. If I search for the exact wording then I get the exact result, **BUT** if I search for **university nowhere** i.e without the "of", then I get nothing..

Example SQL statement:

```
SELECT univ_name FROM university WHERE INSTR(univ_name,'--keyword here--')
```

Any suggestions on what is lacking on my sql statement?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: sorry about that, I added now the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the `LIKE` keyword:

```
SELECT univ_name FROM university WHERE univ_name LIKE '%University%;
```

`%` is a wildcard operator that will return the column where the text contains the word `University`

Comment: the answer should probably help OP with replacing any spaces in the original string with this char dynamically...

Comment: Does your data have it stored as `University` or `university`? It'll probably be case-sensitive.

Comment: hmmm.. I think it's not case-sensitive, since when I tried searching **JUST** the keyword "university" it displays the result properly regardless if it's uppercase or lowercase.. but when I tried "university nowhere" then no result..

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a little trickier than you might think.

Lets start with @searchTerm varchar(max)

What you need to do is dynamically build your where clause by splitting @searchTerm on the space and building it to look something like this:

`where univ_name like '%term0%' AND univ_Name like '%term1%'`

Refer to this question for the general strat on splitting strings in sql
[splitting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

you store this in a varchar(max), lets say @sql

then set `@sql = ''select * from university ' + @sql`

finally run `EXEC (@sql)`